# DataForm / DataView Webpart

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Is it possible to use a dataform or data view webpart to get items from a subsite without using data sources (soap) using SPD only.
I need to be able to filter the form using date to see only certain items.

I have already built a custom DFWP using soap data source to get info from a subsite but I cant seem to filter using dates (i.e. no > or < operator available in the filter section of DFWP.

For instance in DFWP I find this code as part of the select and it doesnt seem to be using CAML as described here ([SPDataSource and Rollups](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2007/04/24/spdatasource-and-rollups-with-the-data-view.aspx) ):

```
<SharePoint:SPDataSource runat="server" DataSourceMode="List" UseInternalName="true" UseServerDataFormat="true" selectcommand="&lt;View&gt;&lt;Query&gt;&lt;Where&gt;&lt;Eq&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;ID&quot;/&gt;&lt;Value Type=&quot;Counter&quot;&gt;101&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;/Eq&gt;&lt;/Where&gt;&lt;/Query&gt;&lt;/View&gt;" id="dataformwebpart1"><SelectParameters><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter Name="ListID" ParameterKey="ListID" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="{E47A2FD2-2DB9-4899-855A-11C9CBC3D09A}"/><asp:Parameter Name="StartRowIndex" DefaultValue="0"/><asp:Parameter Name="nextpagedata" DefaultValue="0"/><asp:Parameter Name="MaximumRows" DefaultValue="10"/></SelectParameters><DeleteParameters><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter Name="ListID" ParameterKey="ListID" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="{E47A2FD2-2DB9-4899-855A-11C9CBC3D09A}"/></DeleteParameters><UpdateParameters><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter Name="ListID" ParameterKey="ListID" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="{E47A2FD2-2DB9-4899-855A-11C9CBC3D09A}"/></UpdateParameters><InsertParameters><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter Name="ListID" ParameterKey="ListID" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="{E47A2FD2-2DB9-4899-855A-11C9CBC3D09A}"/></InsertParameters></SharePoint:SPDataSource></DataSources>
```

Thanks

UDATE:ive added a DFWP to a new page and used a local list, then I switched the code to read from another list in a subsite but i reciece an error 'non-specific error'
In the code I changed all the guids to the new list guid and also changed the data souce line as below (note: added webURL):

```
<DataSources>



<SharePoint:SPDataSource runat="server" DataSourceMode="List" UseInternalName="true" UseServerDataFormat="True" selectcommand="&lt;View&gt;&lt;/View&gt;" id="dataformwebpart1"><SelectParameters><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter Name="ListItemId" ParameterKey="ListItemId" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="0"/><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter Name="ListID" ParameterKey="ListID" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="{1579AB80-C898-4B60-B527-050D356F2955}"/><asp:Parameter Name="StartRowIndex" DefaultValue="0"/><asp:Parameter Name="nextpagedata" DefaultValue="0"/><asp:Parameter Name="MaximumRows" DefaultValue="10"/><asp:Parameter runat=”server” Name=”WebUrl” DefaultValue="/SRE" /></SelectParameters></SharePoint:SPDataSource></DataSources>
```

Comment: `SPDataSource` has `selectcommand` property. That can can be used. The CAML query is in URL Encoded format.

Comment: Just updated question